# extract rows with common characters in a column by comparing two data.frame

Tags: r

How can compare two data.frame (df1 and df2) and extract the rows with common gene names

df1 =

```
logp    chr start   end CNA Genes   No.of.genes
25.714.697  1   90100868    90212160    gain    Iqca,Ackr3  2
2.213.423   1   175422136   176019087   loss    Rgs7,Fh1,Kmo,Opn3,Chml,Wdr64,Gm25560,Exo1,Gm23805,Pld5,B020018G12Rik    11
5.607.005   2   145619035   147312698   gain    Slc24a3,Rin2,Naa20,Crnkl1,4930529M08Rik,Insm1,Ralgapa2,Xrn2,Nkx2-4,Nkx2-2,Gm22261   11
3.756.075   2   141246149   141653989   loss    Macrod2 1
4.852.608   2   41586450    41739605    loss    Lrp1b   1
590.684 2   86729423    86860061    loss    Olfr1089,Olfr1090,Olfr1093,Olfr1093,Olfr141,Olfr1094,Olfr1094,Olfr1095  8
5.721.239   3   25408115    25519319    gain    Nlgn1   1
4.295.527   3   92005564    92134972    gain    Pglyrp3,Prr9    2
4.257.749   3   15244004    15897870    gain    Gm9733,Gm9733,Gm9733,Gm9733,Sirpb1a,Sirpb1a,Sirpb1a,Sirpb1a,Sirpb1b,Sirpb1b,Sirpb1b,Sirpb1b,Sirpb1c,Sirpb1c,Sirpb1c,Sirpb1c 16
418.259 3   154861710   155490219   loss    Tnni3k,Tnni3k,Fpgt,Gm26456,Lrriq3   5
2.284.327   4   134885344   137474898   gain    Rhd,Rhd,Tmem50a,D4Wsu53e,Syf2,Runx3,Clic4,Srrm1,Ncmap,Rcan3,Nipal3,Stpg1,Gm25317,Grhl3,Gm23106,Ifnlr1,Il22ra1,Myom3,Srsf10,Pnrc2,Pnrc2,Cnr2,Fuca1,Hmgcl,Gale,Lypla2,Pithd1,Tceb3,Rpl11,Gm26001,Id3,E2f2,Asap3,Tcea3,Zfp46,Hnrnpr,Htr1d,Luzp1,Kdm1a,4930549C01Rik,Lactbl1,Ephb2,C1qb,C1qc,C1qa,Epha8,Zbtb40,Gm23834,Gm23834,Wnt4,Cdc42,Gm13011,Gm13011,Cela3b,Cela3b,Hspg2   56
1.017.899   4   108176679   108417038   gain    Echdc2,Zyg11a,Zyg11b,Selrc1,Fam159a,Gpx7    6
2.229.929   4   80406963    83998058    gain    Tyrp1,Lurap1l,Mpdz,n-R5s187,Nfib,Zdhhc21,Cer1,Frem1,Ttc39b,Gm23412,Snapc3,Psip1,Ccdc171,Gm25899,Gm25899 15
279.458 4   110534756   110628705   gain    Agbl4   1
1.103.167   4   121565222   124833802   gain    Ppt1,Cap1,Mfsd2a,Mycl,Trit1,Bmp8b,Bmp8b,Oxct2b,Ppie,Hpcal4,Nt5c1a,Heyl,Pabpc4,Gm25788,Gm22154,Bmp8a,Bmp8a,Oxct2a,Macf1,Ndufs5,Akirin1,Rhbdl2,Mycbp,Rragc,Gm22983,Pou3f1,Utp11l,Gm24480,Fhl3,Sf3a3,Inpp5b,Mtf1,n-R5s192  33
1.781.441   4   139917291   140083763   loss    Klhdc7a,Igsf21  2
6.829.744   6   147086557   147179673   gain    Mansc4,Klhl42   2
1.070.905   6   63350920    64077379    loss    Grid2   1
3.132.886   7   17188025    18205037    gain    Psg29,Ceacam5,Ceacam14,Gm5155,Ceacam11,Ceacam13,Ceacam12,Igfl3,Igfl3    9
591.926 7   26773232    26976928    gain    Cyp2a5,Cyp2a5,Cyp2a5,Cyp2a22,Cyp2a22,Cyp2a22    6
4.170.656   7   20654493    24128503    gain    Nlrp4e,Nlrp5,Gm10175,Zfp180,Zfp112  5
2.494.001   7   38898625    38991306    loss    Gm21142,Gm25671 2
13.222.294  7   67330026    67943164    loss    Mef2a,Lrrc28,Gm23233,Ttc23,Synm 5
1.330.269   7   7171339 10865583    loss    Zfp418,Clcn4-2,Zik1,Nlrp4b  4
3.414.431   8   49942996    51497632    loss    Gm23986 1
3.059.542   9   21959210    22072123    gain    Epor,Rgl3,Ccdc151,Prkcsh,Elavl3,Zfp653  6
5.277.845   10  80335500    80575991    gain    Reep6,Adamtsl5,Plk5,Mex3d,Mbd3,Uqcr11,Uqcr11,Tcf3,Gm25044,Gm25044,Gm25044,Gm25044,Onecut3,Atp8b3,Rexo1,Klf16    16
26.812.338  10  100597718   100692256   loss    1700017N19Rik   1
6.998.267   11  60393963    60504695    gain    Lrrc48,Atpaf2,Gid4,Drg2,Myo15   5
2.624.723   11  75676344    76212635    gain    Crk,Ywhae,Doc2b,Rph3al,1700016K19Rik,Fam101b,Vps53,Glod4,Fam57a,Gemin4  10
11.851.916  11  97742687    97853778    gain    Pip4k2b,Cwc25,1700001P01Rik,Rpl23,SNORA21,Snora21,Lasp1 7
3.553.325   11  74899198    75121318    loss    Tsr1,Srr,Smg6,Gm22733   4
309.751 11  105624215   107309569   loss    Tanc2,Cyb561,Ace,Ace,Kcnh6,Dcaf7,Taco1,Map3k3,Limd2,Strada,Ccdc47,Ddx42,Ftsj3,Psmc5,Gm23645,Smarcd2,Tcam1,Gh,Gh,Gh,Gh,Gh,Cd79b,Scn4a,2310007L24Rik,Icam2,Ern1,Snord104,Gm22711,Tex2,Milr1,Gm25889,Polg2,Ddx5,Cep95,Smurf2,Bptf,Nol11,Pitpnc1    39
2.642.471   11  30118384    30155192    loss    Sptbn1  1
10.304.184  12  114641806   116183315   gain    Ighv1-73,Ighv1-83,Zfp386,Zfp386,Zfp386,Zfp386,Zfp386,Zfp386,Zfp386,Zfp386,Vipr2 11
1.414.343   12  116239354   117192837   loss    Wdr60,Esyt2,Ncapg2,Gm25112,Gm24354,Ptprn2   6
2.875.469   14  10676764    10768859    loss    Fhit    1
7.743.121   14  52237972    52331429    loss    Rab2b,Gm23758,Tox4,Mettl3,Sall2 5
2.689.596   14  43932587    45325020    loss    Ang5,Ang6,Ear2,Ear2,Ptgdr,Ptger2,Txndc16,Gpr137c,Ero1l  9
1.912.962   14  119385279   119496386   loss    Hs6st3  1
950.029 14  118589508   118681878   loss    Abcc4   1
4.105.345   14  3004822 8437757 loss    Flnb,Dnase1l3,Abhd6,Rpp14,Rpp14,Pxk,Pdhb,Kctd6,Acox2,Fam107a,Oit1,4930452B06Rik 12
1.870.555   16  33446020    33668062    loss    Zfp148,Slc12a8  2
3.148.258   17  5087550 8333690 gain    Arid1b,Tmem242,Zdhhc14,Snx9,Synj2,Serac1,Gtf2h5,Tulp4,n-R5s26,Tmem181a,Dynlt1a,Dynlt1b,Tmem181b-ps,Tmem181b-ps,Dynlt1c,Tmem181c-ps,Dynlt1f,Sytl3,Ezr,Rsph3b,Tagap1,Rnaset2b,Rnaset2b,Gm25119,Rps6ka2,Ttll2,Gm9992,Gm26057,Fndc1,Tagap,Rsph3a,Gm22416,Rnaset2a,Rnaset2a,Fgfr1op,Ccr6,Mpc1,Sft2d1 38
50.819.398  17  40052632    40331607    gain    Gm7148,Pgk2,Crisp3,Crisp1   4
4.099.936   17  14074943    15508274    loss    Dact2,Smoc2,Thbs2,Gm23352,Wdr27,1600012H06Rik,Phf10,Gm3417,9030025P20Rik,Gm3448,Gm3435,Tcte3,Ermard,Dll1,Fam120b,Psmb1,Tbp  17
12.022.555  17  30590875    31053645    loss    Glo1,Dnah8,Gm24661,Gm24661,Gm24661,Gm24661,Gm24661,Gm24661,Gm24661,Gm24661,Glp1r,Umodl1 12
5.135.466   17  36160573    36277761    loss    Gm22453,Rpp21,Trim39    3
4.254.769   17  27372278    27593833    loss    Grm4,Hmga1,Nudt3    3
5.565.997   18  87905985    87999255    loss    Gm24987,Gm24987 2
```

df2 =

```
Recursive_level logp    chr start   end CNA Genes   No.of.Gene
1   1.416.541   1   68580000    68640000    loss    Erbb4   1
1   7.876.897   1   173840000   174010000   loss    Mndal,Mnda,Ifi203,Ifi202b   4
1   6.280.751   1   173500000   173660000   loss    BC094916,Pydc4,Pyhin1   3
1   7.369.317   1   115900000   116280000   loss    Cntnap5a    1
2   128.766 2   146170000   146660000   gain    4930529M08Rik,Insm1,Ralgapa2    3
1   5.777.222   2   76720000    76800000    loss    Ttn 1
2   1.448.913   3   15360000    16000000    loss    Sirpb1a,Sirpb1a,Sirpb1a,Sirpb1a,Sirpb1b,Sirpb1b,Sirpb1b,Sirpb1b,Sirpb1c,Sirpb1c,Sirpb1c,Sirpb1c 12
1   3.845.977   4   119500000   125160000   gain    AA415398,AA415398,AA415398,AA415398,AA415398,Foxj3,Guca2a,Guca2b,Hivep3,Edn2,Foxo6,Scmh1,Slfnl1,Ctps,Cited4,Kcnq4,Nfyc,Mir30c-1,Mir30e,Rims3,Exo5,Zfp69,Smap2,Col9a2,Zmpste24,Tmco2,Rlf,Ppt1,Cap1,Mfsd2a,Mycl,Trit1,Bmp8b,Bmp8b,Oxct2b,Ppie,Hpcal4,Nt5c1a,Heyl,Pabpc4,Bmp8a,Bmp8a,Oxct2a,Macf1,Ndufs5,Akirin1,Rhbdl2,Mycbp,Rragc,Pou3f1,Utp11l,Fhl3,Sf3a3,Inpp5b,Mtf1,n-R5s192,1110065P20Rik,Yrdc,Maneal,Cdca8,Rspo1,Gnl2,Dnali1,Snip1,Meaf6,Zc3h12a    66
1   1.446.699   4   73900000    74180000    gain    Frmd3   1
1   2.262.305   4   72740000    72880000    gain    Aldoart1    1
1   1.234.215   4   80820000    84340000    gain    Tyrp1,Lurap1l,Mpdz,n-R5s187,Nfib,Zdhhc21,Cer1,Frem1,Ttc39b,Snapc3,Psip1,Ccdc171,Bnc2    13
1   123.671 4   108480000   108760000   gain    Zcchc11,Prpf38a,Orc1,Cc2d1b,Zfyve9  5
1   1.418.261   4   139400000   147600000   loss    Ubr4,Iffo2,Aldh4a1,Tas1r2,Pax7,Klhdc7a,Igsf21,Arhgef10l,Rcc2,Padi4,Padi3,Padi1,Padi2,Sdhb,Atp13a2,Mfap2,Crocc,Necap2,Spata21,Szrd1,Fbxo42,Rsg1,Arhgef19,Epha2,Fam131c,Clcnka,Clcnka,Clcnkb,Clcnkb,Hspb7,Zbtb17,Spen,Fblim1,Tmem82,Slc25a34,Plekhm2,Ddi2,Rsc1a1,Agmat,Dnajc16,Casp9,Cela2a,Cela2a,Ctrc,Efhd2,Fhad1,Tmem51,Kazn,Prdm2,Pdpn,Lrrc38,1700012P22Rik,Aadacl3,9430007A20Rik,Dhrs3,Vps13d,Tnfrsf1b,Tnfrsf8,Zfp600,Zfp600,Rex2    61
1   8.113.817   6   129740000   129800000   gain    Klri2   1
1   15.569.108  6   41360000    41480000    loss    Prss3,Prss3,Prss1,Prss1 4
1   2.037.683   6   63480000    63700000    loss    Grid2   1
2   14.694  7   38260000    38280000    gain    Pop4    1
1   14.946  7   35780000    38280000    gain    Zfp507,Tshz3,Zfp536,Uri1,Ccne1,1600014C10Rik,Plekhf1,Pop4   8
1   7.192.011   7   47500000    47620000    loss    Mrgpra2b,Mrgpra3    2
1   1.722.108   7   26000000    26200000    loss    Cyp2b13,Cyp2b9  2
1   12.683.495  7   11350000    11680000    loss    Zscan4f 1
1   1.360.954   10  80900000    81100000    gain    Timm13,Lmnb2,Gadd45b,Gng7,Diras1,Slc39a3,Sgta,Thop1,Creb3l3 9
1   267.959 11  97880000    98000000    gain    Fbxo47,Plxdc1,Arl5c 3
1   1.872.174   11  75860000    76420000    gain    Rph3al,1700016K19Rik,Fam101b,Vps53,Glod4,Fam57a,Gemin4,Rnmtl1,Nxn,Timm22,Abr    11
1   2.811.352   12  113560000   114920000   gain    Ighv14-3,Ighv13-1,Ighv13-1,Ighv13-1,Ighv13-1,Ighv13-1,Ighv6-4,Ighv6-4,Ighv6-4,Ighv6-4,Ighv6-4,Ighv6-5,Ighv6-5,Ighv6-5,Ighv6-5,Ighv6-5   16
1   1.979.667   12  115860000   115980000   loss    Ighv1-83    1
1   2.098.521   12  17420000    21160000    loss    Nol10,Odc1,Hpcal1,5730507C01Rik,Asap2   5
1   21.864.853  13  12580000    12650000    loss    Ero1lb  1
1   3.233.185   13  61500000    62780000    loss    Ctsm,Cts3,Zfp808    3
1   5.640.895   14  53540000    53780000    gain    Trav12-2,Trav12-3,Trav13-2,Trav14-2,Trav15-2-dv6-2,Trav3-3,Trav9-4,Trav9-4,Trav9-4,Trav9-4,Trav4-4-dv10,Trav5-4,Trav6-7-dv9,Trav7-6,Trav7-6,Trav7-6,Trav16,Trav13-4-dv7,Trav14-3,Trav3-4    20
1   2.942.081   14  86300000    97240000    gain    Diap3,Tdrd3,Rps3a2,Pcdh20,Pcdh9,Klhl1   6
1   4.662.806   14  9840000 9880000 loss    Fhit    1
1   3.638.346   14  43740000    44640000    loss    Ear1,Ear1,Ear10,Ear10,Ang5,Ang6,Ear2,Ear2   8
1   1.709.546   14  35320000    37400000    loss    Grid1,n-R5s46,Ccser2,Rgr,Lrit1,Lrit2,Cdhr1,2610528A11Rik,Ghitm  9
2   3.387.282   14  84060000    85740000    loss    Pcdh17  1
1   2.140.909   14  68280000    86300000    loss    Adam7,Adamdec1,Adam28,Stc1,Nkx2-6,Nkx3-1,Slc25a37,Synb,Entpd4,SYNB,Loxl2,R3hcc1,Chmp7,Tnfrsf10b,Tnfrsf10b,Tnfrsf10b,Tnfrsf10b,Rhobtb2,Pebp4,Egr3,Bin3,Ccar2,9930012K11Rik,9930012K11Rik,Pdlim2,Sorbs3,Ppp3cc,Slc39a14,Piwil2,Polr3d,Mir320,Phyhip,Bmp1,Sftpc,Lgi3,Reep4,Hr,Nudt18,Fam160b2,Dmtn,Fgf17,Npm2,Xpo7,Dok2,Gfra2,Fndc3a,Cysltr2,Rcbtb2,Rb1,Lpar6,Itm2b,Med4,Nudt15,Sucla2,Htr2a,Esd,Lrch1,5031414D18Rik,Lrrc63,Lcp1,Cpb2,Zc3h13,Siah3,Spert,Cog3,Slc25a30,Tpt1,Snora31,Gtf2f2,Kctd4,Gpalpp1,Nufip1,Rps2-ps6,Tsc22d1,Serp2,Lacc1,Ccdc122,Enox1,n-R5s48,Dnajc15,Epsti1,Fam216b,Tnfsf11,Akap11,Dgkh,Vwa8,Zfp957,Rgcc,Naa16,Mtrf1,Kbtbd7,Zbtbd6,Wbp4,Elf1,Sugt1,Lect1,Pcdh8,Olfm4,Pcdh17  99
1   3.810.267   14  109680000   111240000   loss    n-R5s50,Slitrk6 2
1   3.924.724   15  77460000    77560000    loss    Apol10a,Apol10a,Apol10a,Apol10a,Apol11a,Apol11a,Apol11a,Apol11a,Apol7c  9
1   7.728.161   16  44780000    44920000    gain    Cd200r1,Cd200r1,Cd200r4,Cd200r4,Cd200r2,Cd200r2 6
1   348.511 17  73500000    76640000    gain    Galnt14,Ehd3,Xdh,Memo1,Dpy30,Spast,Slc30a6,Nlrc4,Yipf4,Birc6,Ttc27,Ltbp1,Rasgrp3,Fam98a 14
1   1.052.043   17  36120000    36540000    gain    Rpp21,Trim39    2
1   1.325.386   17  90420000    90540000    loss    Nrxn1   1
1   4.438.061   17  38300000    38360000    loss    Olfr137,Olfr137 2
1   125.062 17  30380000    30920000    loss    Btbd9,Glo1,Dnah8,Glp1r  4
1   2.998.359   19  13860000    13900000    gain    Olfr1502    1
2   3.307.524   19  30910000    30970000    loss    Prkg1   1
```

When i tried 
df2[mapply(function(x, y)  length(intersect(x,y))>0,
           strsplit(df1$Gene, ','), strsplit(df2$Gene, ',')),]

i got out

```
logp chr    start      end  CNA    Genes No.of.genes
39 2.689.596  14 43932587 45325020 loss Ang5,Ang6,Ear2,Ear2,Ptgdr,Ptger2,Txndc16,Gpr137c,Ero1l           9
```

But i can find many rows with at least one common Gene

Comment: Could you show the expected result.  `Pekg` is common for both `df1` and `df2`.  So, I guess that would be included.  But, in the 3rd and 4th rows, in addition to `Sox1`, there are other  genes also in `df1`

Comment: I guess the OP wants to extract rows with at least one common Gene, otherwise it would have been easy for the OP to do.

Comment: @naltiper you are correct

Comment: @beginner You could try `strsplit` to split up the `Gene` column` and then do the match.  Perhaps `df2[mapply(function(x,y) any(x %in% y), strsplit(df1$Gene, ','), strsplit(df2$Gene, ",")),]`

Comment: @akrun Add it as answer, I think it covers the OP completely.

Comment: @beginner Can you provide a new example?

Comment: @akrun, please see the updated question..Im not sure if this is the right way of posting a question

Comment: @beginner Thanks for the example.  It would have been to `dput` it.  But, anyway, I will try

Comment: @beginner Based on the example, the dimensions are different.  `nrow(df1)
#[1] 50; nrow(df2)#[1] 46`

Comment: @beginner I tried with the nrow=46 for each dataset. I didn't get any intersection for each of the corresponding element. `mapply(function(x,y) length(intersect(x,y)), strsplit(df1$Gene[1:46], ','), strsplit(df2$Gene, ','))
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[39] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`

Comment: @akrun, thats what i meant.IM curious to know if there is any ways by which we can find gene match between two different datasets  even if its present in different row.

Comment: @beginner So far I was under the impression that you want to match row by corresponding row.  In this case, you could use a double loop

Comment: Perhaps `df2[ sapply(strsplit(df2$Gene, ','), function(x) any(sapply(strsplit(df1$Gene, ','), function(y) any(x %in% y)))),]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could split up the "Genes" column in each datasets with `strsplit`, then compare the corresponding list elements with `mapply`, check if there is `any` intersect and use that index to subset the "df2"

```
 df2[mapply(function(x,y) any(x %in% y),
         strsplit(df1$Gene, ','), strsplit(df2$Gene, ",")),]
 #   chr start  end                Gene
 #1 1179  3360 gain Recl,Bcl,Trim3,Pop4
 #3 7180  9229 loss                Sox1
 #4 8159  8360 loss                Sox1
 #5 9154 10588 loss                Pekg
```

Or use `intersect` and `length`

```
  df2[mapply(function(x, y)  length(intersect(x,y))>0,
       strsplit(df1$Gene, ','), strsplit(df2$Gene, ',')),]
```

#### Update

If we need to find whether a single "Gene" of first dataset is found in any of the rows of second data (using the updated dataset)

```
df2[sapply(strsplit(df2$Gene, ','), function(x) 
  any(sapply(strsplit(df1$Gene, ','), function(y) any(x %in% y)))),]
```

Comment: That worked fine in this case. But when i tried this to a large dataset with more gene names i am not extract rows with at least one common gene.

Comment: You should edit your post and add that dataset then which produces that wrong behaviour, specifically the rows which are not extracted.

Comment: @beginner My post was based on the example provided and the pattern showed. As naltipar commented, it may be better to post some example with the problem described.